# Undefined control sequence when using \setupinteraction and \externalfigure

Tags: graphics, errors, context

When I use `\externalfigure` after `\setupinteraction[state=start]`, I get an error message about an `Undefined control sequence`. Here is a minimal working example (filename `prob.tex`):

```
\starttext
\setupinteraction[state=start]
\externalfigure[star]
\stoptext
```

where `star.pdf` is a small PDF file (and has no known problems). Now when I call ConTeXt on it (Mk iv):

```
$ context prob
[...]
system          > tex > error on line 4 in file prob.tex: Undefined control sequence ...

1     \starttext
2     \setupinteraction[state=start]
3     \externalfigure[star]
4 >>  \stoptext
```

By contrast, if I comment out the `\setupinteraction` command (or set e.g. `state=stop`), it compiles fine. It also compiles fine if I remove the `\externalfigure` command, which is what makes me believe that the *combination* of the two commands is necessary to cause the error.

What am I doing wrong (or is this expected)? I'd like to have interactive links in the PDF, hence the `\setupinteraction`.

Thanks in advance!

My sincere apologies if this has already been asked. I looked around (`[context] setupinteraction externalfigure`, using Google, Bing and the Duck thingy) and found nothing.

Details:

```
$ context --version

mtx-context     | ConTeXt Process Management 0.60
mtx-context     |
mtx-context     | main context file: /opt/context-minimals/texmf-context/tex/context/base/context.mkiv
mtx-context     | current version: 2012.06.26 10:59

$ uname -a
Linux tj-desktop 3.4.4-2-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Sun Jun 24 17:28:37 UTC 2012 i686 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: I tried compiling your exact example, and it did work for me. I ran it first with MkIV 2012.05.dd (I forget the day); then, because your version was later than mine, I updated with `cd /opt/context` followed by `./first-setup.sh --keep`, and found the MWE also compiles with MkIV 2012.07.10. Perhaps this is a bug specific to the 2012.06.26 version? If you could try updating your ConTeXt, then letting me know (with @Esteis in your comment) whether the problem persists, that would be grand. Also: welcome to the TeX Stack Exchange!

Comment: @Esteis It works!  So it was just a version issue, as you supposed. Should have thought of that. Thank you very, very much - this was slowly driving me crazy.

Comment: Congratulations! In that case, I'll just write that in an answer; and if you could accept it, that'll get this question off the 'unanswered' list. We'll keep the question up for now, as it concerns a recent version; but perhaps in a few months we can delete it as 'too localized', as it will apply only to people who will have updated ConTeXt in the week of 2012.06.26, and not since then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug with the 2012.06.26 beta. Update ConTeXt with

```
cd /opt/context
sh ./first-setup.sh --keep
```

and all will be well.

Comment: Incidentally, in my case there was no `first-setup.sh` in `/opt/context`, most probably because I had installed via my distro's installer. The bottom line is: just upgrade, either by hand or using your platform's package manager.